# thmtools. How do I customize it?

Tags: thmtools

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}    % Enable Type 1 font encoding (Cork Encoding)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage[american,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{soul} % to use \ul{}, underline on more line
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition} % use upright lettering
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheorem[name=Claim,numberwithin=section]{claim}

\newcommand{\cl}[1]{
    \begin{claim}[{#1}] 
        {{\bf{\ul{#1.}}}}\end{claim}
    }
 
\begin{document}
\listoftheorems[show={claim},title={Claims}]
\section{Intro}
\cl{First} FIRST TEXT
\cl{Second} SECOND TEXT
\end{document}
```

How do I avoid the elements I do not need, as in the screenshot below?

[image: output I would like]

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated: Never use `\bf`, it has been depreciated since 1993. Secondly `\bf` does not take an argument.

Comment: Yes, of course, \textbf{} is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to achieve this, but this can probably serve as a starting point. The package you choose is probably not the best way to achieve what you want considering that quite a lot of tweaking is needed.

For example, it seems to be not very straighforward to tweak the format of the entries in the list of theorems. Therefore, it seems to be easier to override the name of the theorems with `{}` and create a custom style via `\declaretheoremstyle` and place the name of the theorems using the `headformat` option there. The parenthesis in the list of theorems can be deleted by redefining `\thmtformatoptarg`.

You can then use your approach to style the note of the theorem. You approach actually seems to be the most feasible way to do this, because using `\ul` inside the `headformat` option (the use of which would be quite obvious otherwise) seems to result in errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{soul} % to use \ul{}, underline on more line
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition} % use upright lettering
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheoremstyle[headformat={Claim \NUMBER}]{claim}
\declaretheorem[name={},numberwithin=section,style=claim]{claim}

\newcommand{\cl}[1]{
    \begin{claim}[#1]\textbf{\ul{#1.}}\end{claim}
}
\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems[show={claim},title={Claims}]
\section{Intro}
\cl{First} FIRST TEXT
\cl{Second} SECOND TEXT
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

Since the OP added some requirements in their comments to this post, here is another version where the list of theorems is styled a bit differently. For this to work, the latest version of the package `thmtools` (at least v0.72) is needed which supports the option `swapnumber` for `\listoftheorems`:

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{soul} % to use \ul{}, underline on more line
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition} % use upright lettering
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheoremstyle[headformat={Claim \NUMBER}]{claim}
\declaretheorem[name=Claim,numberwithin=section,style=claim]{claim}

\newcommand{\cl}[1]{
    \begin{claim}[#1]\textbf{\ul{#1.}}\end{claim}
}
\renewcommand{\thmtformatoptarg}[1]{. #1}

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems[show={claim},title={Claims},swapnumber]
\section{Intro}
\cl{First} FIRST TEXT
\cl{Second} SECOND TEXT
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: WOW!  Perfect, thanks so much. (Do you happen to know how to insert 'claim' in the list before numbering: `claim 1.1 First .... 1`? )

Comment: The very latest version of `thmtools` (v0.72) has `swapnumber` as an option to `\listoftheorems`. Maybe you can use this. You would need to set the option `name` of the macro `\declaretheorem` to `Claim` as you had it before. I did not try this, since I don't have the current version of `thmtools` at hand. I would suggest you look into the [documentation of the package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/thmtools/doc/thmtools-manual.pdf) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks, I need to learn how to update the package https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610148/how-to-update-a-single-package-on-fedora