# How to update a single package on Fedora

Tags: texlive

I need to update a single package (`thmtools` from v.68 to v.72, see [my issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609623/thmtools-how-do-i-customize-it)).
I am on a Fedora 32 machine (5.11.11-100.fc32.x86_64), and I install/update texlive with the Fedora manager `dnf`. Unfortunately, `thmtools` does not seem to be updated at the Fedora repository.

Do I have  a quick trick to add somehow (by hand?) the updated version of the package without destroy anything?

note, if I try tlmgr I get a Warning not to do it:

```
>> tlmgr update --list
*** WARNING ***: Performing this action will likely destroy the Fedora TeXLive install on your system.
*** WARNING ***: This is almost NEVER what you want to do.
*** WARNING ***: Try using dnf install/update instead.
*** WARNING ***: If performing this action is really what you want to do, pass the "ignore-warning" option.
*** WARNING ***: But please do not file any bugs with the OS Vendor.
```

Comment: An easy way is to download the 2 files `thmtools.ins` and `thmtools.dtx` from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/thmtools/source, save them in the directory of your document, and run `latex thmtools.ins` (note: `latex`, _not_ `pdflatex`). This will create `thmtools.sty` in your directory, and since this is this first place LaTeX looks for packages it will be used when you compile your document.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/how-do-i-install-a-dtx-file, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Answer (score 1):

Look for your local `TEXMF` directory, e.g.

```
echo $TEXMFLOCAL
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
```

then create the directory

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/thmtools
```

Download the zip from CTAN, put the files into that new directory, run

```
latex thmtools.ins
latex thmtools.dtk  (only if you need the documentation ...)
```

then run

```
texhash
```

and now the local file should be used.

Comment: Note that the OP already has an old version of the package, so creating a directory is not needed, instead `kpsewhich thmtools.sty` will give the correct directory to put the new file in.

Comment: No! That is the wrong way, never use the directory of the "official" distribution.

Comment: @Marijn as mentioned never manually install stuff into the main installation. It is better to find the "local" part, for texlive one can use `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL` and it will tell you where the `texmf-local` is and then one should use that.

Comment: @daleif I have heard it is "better", for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees?noredirect=1&lq=1, but the reasons there do not really apply to the use case in this question I think.

Comment: @Marijn I think at least 95% of installations are single user.

Comment: @daleif possibly (although in that case according to Alan Mann you should [use TEXMFHOME and not TEXMFLOCAL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/what-are-texlives-four-different-texmf-folders#comment54914_27986)) but that was not what I was referring to. The reasons listed in the linked question above are: texmf-dist is for official packages (thmtools is an official package), local is for test versions (thmtools on CTAN is not a test version), local is for configuration files (doesn't apply), local is for restricted material (thmtools is not restricted). The only possibly valid [...]

Comment: [...] reason is that an update by a package manager does not work for packages that you have manually placed in texmf-dist. However, while that may apply to `tlmgr`, I think that when Fedora packages a new version of TeX Live with associated package updates it will happily overwrite manual updates, or at least ask the user about it with an option to overwrite. I might be wrong about that though, I'll try if I can confirm this.

Comment: Hi,  for the time being I opted for a dirty way. I rename the old folder to `thmtoolsORi`, and extract the .zip from CTAN to a new folder `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools`, then I run `sudo latex thmtools.ins`. It seems I need to copy all the files from both `source` and `doc` therein, otherwise i get a `I can't find file VERSION.tex. l.4 \input VERSION.tex`. Note `sudo latex thmtools.dtx` fails with `! LaTeX Error: File luximono.sty not found`, but I do not think I need that. I am able to process my project with thmtools v. 072. This is good for now.